# Error creating pivot tables in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have searched and cannot find anyone else with this problem. I am trying to create a pivot table summarizing a csv file, and then email that pivot to myself. I have already built out the code to perform this process, but it is not working universally. I keep getting a KeyError on my column name, but if I delete all columns and rows that are not part of the table it miraculously works.

Here is my code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('/path/to/file'),encoding='utf-8')
pivot = pandas.pivot_table(df,index=['ClientID','ClientName','Branch'],
                           values=['EmailAddress'],aggfunc='count',margins=True)
pivotlocation = '/path/to/save'
pivot.to_csv(pivotlocation)
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is going wrong, or why this works on some files and not others.

Also, here is the error that is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rfulton\Desktop\Automation\Reports\UniversalUpload.py", line 86, in create_pivot
  pivot = pandas.pivot_table(df,index=columns,values=aggvalue,aggfunc='count',margins=True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\pivot.py", line 114, in pivot_table
  grouped = data.groupby(keys)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2898, in groupby
  sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1193, in groupby
  return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 383, in __init__
  level=level, sort=sort)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2131, in _get_grouper
  in_axis, name, gpr = True, gpr, obj[gpr]
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1780, in __getitem__
  return self._getitem_column(key)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1787, in _getitem_column
  return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1068, in _get_item_cache
  values = self._data.get(item)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2849, in get
  loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1402, in get_loc
  return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
File "pandas\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3807)
File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3687)
File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12310)
File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12261)
KeyError: 'ClientID'
```

As I stated above, if I delete all cells outside the bounds of the table, this error is no longer thrown. However, I am not sure of how to do this with the csv or pandas modules.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was the encoding of the file.
Setting the encoding to *utf-8-sig* fixed the issue.